# Create a project using foundation and sass syntax?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I just installed the 'foundation' (v.1.0.4) gem with ruby 2.1.2 and I want to create a project using the sass syntax, not scss.  I would have thought that the 'foundation' command used to create a new project would offer a "--syntax sass" option but it appears its only options are:
Options:
  [--libsass], [--no-libsass]
  [--version=VERSION]

Amazingly, I can't find any documentation for the 'foundation' command that lets me create a new project with sass syntax.  It's like the sass syntax has just disappeared off the face of the earth hehe.  I can't seem to find any mention of it anywhere on the foundation site.

Does anyone know how I can do that?  Blessings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sass-convert -F scss -T sass --recursive scssFolder sassFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

With compass you can convert from one syntax to another(see config.rb)

[Or with sass command line:](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/#_2)

> sass-convert
>
> The sass-convert executable converts between CSS, Sass, and SCSS. When
>   converting from CSS to Sass or SCSS, nesting is applied where
>   appropriate. See sass-convert --help for further information and
>   options.

Comment: Thanks!  sass-convert will get me going.  But as far as compass is concerned am I right that compass no longer works with the new foundation gem?  If I run "compass create xx --syntax sass --using foundation -r foundation" I get "cannot load such file -- foundation".  Or can you elaborate on "With compass you can convert from one syntax to another"..thanks again!

Comment: @Craig they updated the instillation guide foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html you can use compass, for example, to auto compile sass files on change with "compass watch" but you create project with "foundation new PROJECT_NAME"

Comment: thanks JAre.  I saw that but the problem is that it appears that the 'foundation' command has no support for creating the project with .sass files instead of .scss
For example, the 'foundation new' command help says the only options are:
Options:
  [--libsass], [--no-libsass]  
  [--version=VERSION]

Comment: @Craig you should be able to create project with the default syntax and then convert the whole thing. Also you can simply clone Foundation from the GitHub and convert it - it's just a set of scss files there is no magic.